# How to prevent wrapping of parentheses around elements in JSX

Tags: jsx, eslint, webstorm, prettier

How to prevent wrapping components by parentheses in JSX?

My desired form of component:

```
return <Component />
```

But it becomes like below:

```
return (
    <Component />
)
```

I using WebStorm IDE, Prettier and ESLint.

Comment: Must be related to this ESLint rule: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-wrap-multilines.md#return